# How to pass session id from one page to another in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

```
Response.Redirect("Password_ret.aspx?userid="+TextBox1.Text);
```

sends the data present in the text box to password_ret page

Similarly, 
What command should I use for

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to send the data to the next page. I am using

```
Response.Redirect("Feedback.aspx?Session_ID=" ??what should be used here??);
```

Session_ID is a field in my database

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the session ID in a cookie

Answer (score 0):

To store session information you can use the `Session` object, a `Cookie`, `ViewState`, the `QueryString` or a `Hidden Form` variable. A quick search on StackOverflow or Google should help you decide which is the best option to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the .NET Session ID?

It's available in the field:

```
Session.SessionID
```

If that's what you're after. If you want Session ID's to be passed in the URL instead of using cookies, you may enable it like so, in the web.config:

```
<sessionstate 
  mode="inproc"
  cookieless="true" 
  timeout="20" 
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
DateKeyNames="SessionID"
```

to your GridView declaration.

Then in your code behind:

```
Response.Redirect("Feedback.aspx?Session_ID=" + GridView1.SelectedValue);
```